# How do I update n rows in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to update the first N rows in a table meeting a condition.

I know I can do an Update Top N... but the problem is that N is in a @variable.

UPDATE TOP @N SET ... doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this that I am just missing?

No specific table definitions here because it doesn't matter what the columns are.. If I can do it for a one column table I can do it for my table.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use parens after `TOP` clause when you want to use a variable:

```
UPDATE TOP(@N) ...
```

Comment: Cool trick! Thanks for teaching it to me.  Interestingly, this very syntax does not work with the 'SELECT TOP n' construct.  I can why that would happen, although it is somewhat of an odd asymmetry in TSQL.

Comment: `SELECT TOP n` works only if `n` is a constant, not a variable. It worked like that before 2005. `TOP` with a variable argument and `TOP` for DML statements has been added since 2005 and require parens.

Comment: This would be really cool, however, "update top(@N) set systemuserid = @ID where systemuserid is null" gives me "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'".

Comment: Moose: You need to specify the table you want to update after `TOP(n)` clause. Of course, if order is important to you, you should consider Quassnoi's solution anyway.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot this morning. Helps to give the table name.

Comment: Thanks Mehdad. Not enough caffiene this morning, need to start the IV drip.

Answer (score 10):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  TOP (@r) *
        FROM    mytable
        ORDER BY
                col1
        )
UPDATE  q
SET     co12 = @value
```

`UPDATE TOP (@r)` will work but it will update any `@r` rows **in no particular order**.

From the [**documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

> The rows referenced in the `TOP` expression used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` are not arranged in any order. `TOP n` returns `n` random rows.

Comment: `@KM`: this time I corrected the statement *before* you pointed :)

Comment: +1, I'm hear to learn, so I try out a lot of code, never saw an UPDATE of an CTE, I'll have to play with that a little...

Comment: `@KM`: very useful to delete duplicates. http://explainextended.com/2009/03/14/deleting-duplicates/

Comment: I'm gonna give you a vote because this works too, but I'm not worried about the order. Just need to parcel them out.