# Executing Sql Command only once

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have a Database DB with a table name population but with no Primary Key. Means it can have duplication of data. For example: I have 5 families (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5) with different members inside it (and members may have same name). So I can have exactly same type of record in more than 1 row. Now I want to edit just 1 member of the family, but it is editing all the duplicate records. What I want to do is, I just want to Update my Database once and only once. In other words, I want to use UPDATE command to execute just once. How to do it?
I am using Sql Server Express, VS2010, C# 4.0 (if this info matters).
I am pretty sure my problem may sound stupid to some people (probably many). But it is just a dummy of my problem. Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If the names are duplicate and you don't have a primary key, how would identify the "one" row you want updated?

Comment: hmmm, by checking different column names, and no matter how many rows it encountered to be matching, it has to update just one and exit. but to your query, one upvote

Comment: You still have to answer the question of *which* row to update.

Comment: it has to update the first matching column (based on where clause), and then exit

Comment: "First" is not identified with a WHERE clause. It would require the use of an ORDER BY. So, how do you order the many encountered rows to determine which is "first?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's not exactly what you're asking but seriously, the easiest option is to alter the database to have a primary key and use that.  Perhaps an Identity key....

Without that, you could update just one record, but ***you have no guarantee of which record***.  This is why primary keys are such as fundamental concept.  I suppose this doesn't really matter if they are all the same, so....

If you *really* want to proceed without a primary key, you need to use the TOP keyword as shown here: [How do I update n rows in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487544/how-do-i-update-n-rows-in-a-table)

Set it to

```
UPDATE TOP 1 ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an identity column, ID int with auto increment on. Then update using the id's.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Family
(
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    FamilyName varchar(50) NULL
)

update dbo.Family set FamilyName = 'xxx' where Id = y
```

Comment: surely will consider adding a identity column

Answer (score 1):

In case you can't add an identity column for some reason:

```
UPDATE TOP ( 1 ) Families
SET    Whatever = 'Your Value', ...
WHERE  <Your where clause>
```

Comment: Define "correct."  If the rows are all identical, the idea is to change any one of them.  If the rows are not identical, don't do it this way -- use a WHERE clause that gets the correct row.

Comment: But updating random records is so much easier than finding the right record! Like I always say, It's SO much easier to speculate wildly than to actually do research and find the right answer.

Comment: @Jay Why of course... :)  I can't think of a scenario when I would ever have completely duplicate records in a table _on purpose_, but that's just me.

Comment: @Andrew: Yeah, I'm trying to think of a scenario. Maybe a log file or audit trail could have exact duplicates if the same event happened twice -- but even then you'd likely have timestamps that would differ. Can anybody suggest a scenario? It almost sounds like an interesting puzzle.

Comment: @Jay Even in an audit trail or log file you can throw an identity column on there.  For all the things my predecessors at my current job got wrong in the database (no unique contraint on username?  wtf?  it was fun when _that_ blew up), at least they had the sense to use something for a primary key in the audit tables.

Comment: @Andrew: Oh, absolutely, you always COULD add an identify column. But is there any situation where this would be unnecessary or pointless? I think the answer is no, because you always need a way to uniquely identify a row for update purpose. I was just fishing for whether someone could give a counter-example. Maybe involving a table that has only inserts and no updates? Where any update of such identical rows should update all of them? Just a philosophical musing, really.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is: Fix your database design. Every record should have some unique identifier. Add an auto-increment field or something.

To directly answer your question, you can say "update top (1) ..." to only update one record. But without some unique identifier, how do you know which record to update? The program will essentially update a random record. Which takes me back to point 1.

Edit: Whoops, my original answer was for a different engine. Corrected above.

Comment: i will definitely review my database design and will consider adding a id column. Thanks for your help